# gomock missing call(s)

Tags: go, apache-kafka, gomock

I am trying to mock the below method using gomock

```
func (w *writer) Publish(vacancies []model.Vacancy) error {
    ...

    if _, err = w.conn.WriteMessages(msg); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to write message: %w", err)
    }
```

Interface:

```
type Producer interface {
        Publish(vacancies []model.Vacancy) error
        Close() error
    }
```

SuiteTest:

```
func (p *ProducerTestSuite) SetupTest() {
    p.mockCtrl = gomock.NewController(p.T())
    p.producer = NewMockProducer(p.mockCtrl)
    writer, err := producer.NewWriter(context.Background(), scheduler.KafkaConf{Addr: "localhost:9092", Topic: "test"})
    p.Require().NoError(err)
    p.writer = writer
}
...
func (p *ProducerTestSuite) TestProducer_Publish() {
    p.producer.EXPECT().Publish([]model.Vacancy{}).Return(nil)
    p.Require().NoError(p.writer.Publish([]model.Vacancy{}))
}
```

mockgen:

```
//go:generate mockgen -package producer_test -destination mock_test.go -source ../kafka.go
```

When I try run test, I got this message:

```
=== RUN   TestSuite/TestProducer_Publish
    controller.go:137: missing call(s) to *producer_test.MockProducer.Publish(is equal to [] ([]storage.Vacancy)) /Users/...
    controller.go:137: aborting test due to missing call(s)
```

Where I wrong?

Comment: I see no code which would actually call `Publish` on anything—just setting up a mock.

Comment: p.Require().NoError(**p.writer.Publish([]model.Vacancy{})**)

Comment: Thanks, I see now. May it be that the problem is that you're calling `producer.NewWriter` anfd not `p.producer.NewWriter`? I mean, I would expect that you would obtain a new writer on a mock producer instance. With the code as presented, it looks like the created `writer` has no connection with the producer's mock.

Comment: probably I solved it . https://goplay.space/#bNvv5N9QFjF

Answer (score 8):

This answer is late, but it might helpful.

To require the function to be called once:

```
mockService.EXPECT().DoSomething().Return(nil, nil)
```

To allow the function to be called zero or more times:

```
mockService.EXPECT().DoSomething().Return(nil, nil).AnyTimes()
```

Answer (score 2):

the Expect() means these must be a call to this method with the specified parameter, otherwise it will be failed, the missing call means your set a Expect() but didn't call it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you are not calling the same thing that you are expecting on. Your expect is watching `p.producer.Publish()`, but your test code calls `p.writer.Publish()`. I cannot see any code here that would lead `writer` to call anything in `producer`.

The following code would behave as you expect:

```golang
func (p *ProducerTestSuite) TestProducer_Publish() {
    p.producer.EXPECT().Publish([]model.Vacancy{}).Return(nil)
    p.Require().NoError(p.producer.Publish([]model.Vacancy{}))
}
```

However, this test does not seem to actually exercise the unit that the test name indicates it should. Perhaps you are misunderstanding mocking ?

Answer (score 1):

I also resolved a similar issue by adding a:

```
EXPECT().<interface-method>().Return(...).AnyTimes()
```

It seems that if one sets an EXPECT() gomock assumes that it must be called at least once. Adding AnyTimes() allows it to be called 0 times.